# A type but is used like a variable?

Tags: c#, variables, types

```
    struct Player
    {
        public string Name;
        public int X;
        public int Y;
    }
    static Player[] players = new Player[amountofPlayers];

        for (int i = 1; i < amountofPlayers; i = i + 1)
        {
            int displayNumber = i + 1;
            Console.Write("Please enter the name of player " + displayNumber + ": ");
            Player[i].Name = Console.ReadLine(); // The error is here

        }
```

Can someone help me to fix this, as I cannot see what where I am going wrong...

Comment: it's typo use `players[i]` instead of `Player[i]`.. and better to use `foreach`

Answer (score 8):

`Player` is the type/struct, `players` the `Player[]`, so use this:

```
players[i].Name = Console.ReadLine(); // instead of Player[i]
```

Comment: Thanks for the lightning fast response :P, If I change the code to how you suggested it will no longer store the data inside the struct, any idea how to fix this? Nevermind.

Comment: @user3055553: I must admit that i don't understand what you mean. How do you store the data inside the struct? The variable `players` is a `Player[]` outside of `Player`, now and before.

Comment: I realized what you meant and understood where I went wrong, sorry for the confusion. haha